# How to convert DC +350mv ~ -350mv to 3V ~ 0V

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image]

The operating voltage is +/-3.3V DC, Multiple op amps can be used,
As long as the completion of voltage conversion purposes.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUHqeT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'm simulating at Multisim, Input + 350mv after the output is very beautiful, about 3.25V. But when the input -350mv after the output can not be zero. There are still about -80mv can not be removed.

Comment: This sounds like a garbled rewrite of a homework question.

Comment: Without using the squiggle symbol (that means either AC or approximate) write the input and output ranges with zero possibility of ambiguity.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I am still a student, but I am very serious about learning ^^

Comment: Step one - modern op-amp, not a crufty old part like a 358. your (homework question?) appears to show 3.3V supplies, so expect to get dinged for a "solution" with two 5V batteries...and when they offer you more than one op-amp, consider what benefits you might get, design-wise, from that freedom - and exploit it if it is not a red herring.

Comment: Question significantly improved. Rather than just "modern opamp" I'd suggest reading the opamp's datasheet, learning about its (serious) limitations and how to deal with them. For a start, what is "input offset voltage" * gain?